# Angualrjs Filter array in controller

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have sample Json. I am fiter based on key value.

The fiter didn't sort exact value

Example:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('testController', ['$filter', '$scope',
function($filter, $scope) {

    var obj = '[{"id":"1","m_id":1,"value":"Male"},
                {"id":"2","m_id":1,"value":"Female"},
                {"id":"3","m_id":1,"value":"Other"},
                {"id":"45","m_id":9,"value":"Single"},
                {"id":"46","m_id":9,"value":"Married"},
                {"id":"47","m_id":10,"value":"Father"},
                {"id":"48","m_id":10,"value":"Mother"},
                {"id":"61","m_id":10,"value":"Cousin"},
                {"id":"62","m_id":10,"value":"Other"}]';

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
    var result = $filter('filter')(obj1, {
        m_id : "1"
    });
}]);
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"1","m_id":1,"value":"Male"},
 {"id":"2","m_id":1,"value":"Female"},
 {"id":"3","m_id":1,"value":"Other"},
 {"id":"47","m_id":10,"value":"Father"},
 {"id":"48","m_id":10,"value":"Mother"},
 {"id":"61","m_id":10,"value":"Cousin"},
 {"id":"62","m_id":10,"value":"Other"}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{"id":"1","m_id":1,"value":"Male"},
 {"id":"2","m_id":1,"value":"Female"},
 {"id":"3","m_id":1,"value":"Other"}]
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/U3pVM/23860/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way also, by using [**Javascript Filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var result = obj1.filter(function(v){
    return v.m_id == 1;
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/61fcfozo/)

---

In **AngularJS v.1.1.3** exact filter is [provided natively](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.3/docs/api/ng.filter%3Afilter)

```
var result = $filter('filter')(obj1, 
    {m_id : 1},
    true // ==========> this is for exact match
);
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/917/)

Comment: Question is for Angular  (much more complex filtering system with custom expressions etc etc)

Comment: @Nathan its Native Javascript code which is working.

Comment: That's my point: you've answered it for native JS when the question is for AngularJS.

Comment: Why use framework-specific code when plain JavaScript will do the job just as easily/well? There's nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: @JoeClay because it offers lots of other abilities too

Comment: @Nathan there is no special ability in Angular filter.

Comment: Ah, but there is: read more here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Comment: @Nathan: Not in this particular case, though? The Angular version does the exact same thing but is longer and (in my opinion) less readable. I'm not saying *never* use `$filter`, but in this case, it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @JoeClay see the link:  it fits into a whole presentation / separation of concerns framework.  Trust me, it's awesome.   (Also, if a question is in X then answer the question, don't quibble over why they're using X!!)

Comment: Native `filter` code is more readable and compact to understand.

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: So i have updated answer also with DEMO. Take a look. It solve question and as well gives 2 options.

Comment: Much better: +1 for you :)

Comment: @Nathan: I know what Angular does, I use it at work every day. I'm saying *in this particular situation*, using the `$filter` service doesn't give you any tangible benefits over using the native JS method. If I was writing a more complex filter that I wanted to reuse throughout my app, then I'd use the service.

Comment: Fair enough @JoeClay - but we don't know the scope of his app, so it's a fairly empty conversation and we need to trust that if he's competent enough to be using Angular then he's got a rough idea of where he's heading: might just be starting with getting a basic implementation in place for further extension later etc.

Comment: @Nathan: That's a reasonable argument, to be fair. I'm all for showing them both ways of doing it!

Comment: Where else do you get people scrambling to help with such enthusiasm?  I love SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var result = $filter('filter')(obj1, {
        m_id : "1"
});
```

to

```
var result = $filter('filter')(obj1, function(item) { return item && item.m_id == 1; });
```

**Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt72unwe/2/)**

Comment: I tried but getting same output. (with m_id 1 and 10)

Comment: any other suggestion?